# Button en Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net, visual-studio-2017

vengo aquí a traerles una pregunta, en la primera imagen estoy utilizando un ContextMenuStrip, el cual con el click derecho en el Button Caja se Despliegan las opciones.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que yo quiero es que esas opciones se desplieguen haciendo click en CAJA, y que las opciones aparezcan abajo, algo parecido a esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

luego obviamente si al hacer clic en otro button o en algún lado del formulario, estas opciones deben desaparecen,
si alguien me da una mano le agradecería, cualquier consulta si no me supe explicar bien no duden en preguntar, muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay que usar las propiedades del mouse que actuan sobre el boton principal.
Mouse hover y mouse leave. Cuando el mouse este sobre el boton se haran visibles los otros elementos secundarios.
Cuando esta fuera se deshabilitan.
Con el uso de un timer puedes hacer que desaparezcan, osea hacerlos invisibles.
Y con la propiedad click del Form, si no la necesitas puedes hacer invisibles de nuevo los botones.
Para que se ve un mejor efecto habría que hacer esto a cada boton, cuando estes sobre el boton principal solo te aparezca el primero secundario, luego que estes sobre el primero te aparezca el segundo secuandario y susecivamente.
Pd: En tu caso seria mouse hover y leave sobre el elemento donde tienes el icono de Caja.
Espero te haya servido.
Saluditos!!!!

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private int ticks;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

       //Este es el nombre del evento MouseHover del boton1
        private void EnableButtons(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ticks = 0;            
            timer1.Start();

            label1.Text = ticks.ToString();
            button2.Visible = true;
            button3.Visible = true;
            button4.Visible = true;
        }
        //Este es el nombre del evento MouseLeave del boton1
        private void DisableButtons(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            
            timer1.Start();
            label1.Text = ticks.ToString(); 
            if (ticks>3)
            {
                button2.Visible = false;
                button3.Visible = false;
                button4.Visible = false;
            }

        }
        //Este es un timer de forms
        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ticks++;
        }
            //Este es el evento click del Form
        private void HideButtons(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            button2.Visible = false;
            button3.Visible = false;
            button4.Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: muchas gracias amigo, sos un capo te lo agradezco de verdad